# HTML Markup To Use For Video Transcripts

Tags: html, video, standards, markup

Any idea what the proper containing markup would be to indicate a transcript for a video? Thinking accessibility for folks with disabilities but also perhaps search engine recognition of the association between the text and the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition lists are good for this:

```
<dl class="transcript">
    <dt>Person's name...</dt>
    <dd>What was said</dd>

    <dt>Person's name...</dt>
    <dd>What was said</dd>

    <dt>Person's name...</dt>
    <dd>What was said</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

[<cite>](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/cite/) ? [<q>](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/q/) ?

I usually use [HTML Dog](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/) to check for available tags.